# Firefox not doing spellcheck when working in local environment?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, spell-checking

Quick one from me - is Firefox's spellcheck functionality (I am running ver 37.0.1) disabled when editing websites and apps locally. Words spelled incorrectly are underlined in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

I have added spellcheck="true" to a  field but still no luck.

Everything seems to be working correctly on the pages that are already online.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - Firefox needs a dictionary to be downloaded to spellcheck things.https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Comment: Previously after updating the layout.spellcheckDefault to 2, it used to work fine but i have noticed that with recent version the behavior is no more same. I already have the value for spellchecker.dictionary set to en-US in about:config. I reset the value and then installed the dictionary. Adding a dictionary resulted in a new tab of Dictionary in the Add-on page.